# Stability of critical point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Let $y''+f(t)y=0$ where $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty}f(t)=1$.

> When is the critical point $(0,0)$ stable?

I want to show that this is the case when $\int_0^\infty|f(t')-1|dt'$ is finite.
For this we write $y(t)=A(t)\cos(t)+B(t)\sin(t)$ s.t. $A'\cos(t)+B'\sin(t)=0.$
I have shown that for $C(t)=A^2(t)+B^2(t)$, we have $$C'\leq4|f(t)-1|C.$$
And I want to use this to prove that $(0,0)$ is stable when $\int_0^\infty|f(t')-1|dt'$ is finite.
Plus, I know that stability means that for every neigbourhod $N$ of $(0,0)$ there is a $M\subset N$ s.t. if $y\in M$ then the flow $\phi(t,y)\in N$for all $t$.

What can I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can appoach this using **Lyapunov theory**.

Consider the states $x_1=y$, $x_2=\dot{y}$. 
If you define a Lyapunov function candidate $$V=x_1^2+x_2^2$$
then its derivative takes the form
$$\dot{V}=2(1-f(t))x_1x_2\leq |f(t)-1|V$$

Using now  [Gronwall-Bellman inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) we obtain
$$V(t)\leq V(0)\exp\left(\int_0^t|f(\tau)-1|d\tau\right)$$
from which stability follows if 
$$\int_0^\infty|f(\tau)-1|d\tau\leq C$$
for some $C>0$.